# Lie algebra of linear algebraic group $\operatorname{GL}_n$

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field. Then we can define the algebra of dual numbers $k[\varepsilon]:= k[x]/(x^2)=k\oplus \varepsilon k$, with $\varepsilon^2=0$. We can then also consider the projection $\pi: k[\varepsilon]\to k: a+\varepsilon b\mapsto a$.

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group. The *Lie algebra of $G$* is defined as

$$ \operatorname{Lie}(G):=\ker\left(G(k[\varepsilon])\stackrel{G(\pi)}{\to} G(k)\right).$$

Now, consider the linear algebraic group $G:=\operatorname{GL}_n$. We can show that $$ G(k[\varepsilon])=\{A+\varepsilon B\mid A\in \operatorname{GL}_n(k),B\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(k)\}.$$ Then, by definition, $\operatorname{Lie}(G)=\{I_n+\varepsilon B\mid B\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(k)\}$. I was now wondering why this is, in fact, a Lie algebra. I use following definition:

**Definition.** A *Lie algebra* over $k$ is a $k$-vector space $\mathfrak{g}$, together with a map $[\cdot,\cdot]:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$ such that (1) $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is $k$-bilinear, (2) $[x,x]=0,\forall x\in\mathfrak{g}$, and (3) the well-known Jacobi identity holds.

I need to show that $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ is a $k$-vector space endowed with some Lie bracket operation. For this, we note that $\operatorname{Mat}_n(k)$ has a natural Lie algebra structure, namely $\operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{Mat}_n(k))=\mathfrak{gl}_n$ with $[x,y]:=xy-yx,\forall x,y\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(k)$.

The map $E: \operatorname{Mat}_n(k)\to \operatorname{Lie}(G): B\mapsto I_n+\varepsilon B$ is a bijection. I believe that we need to endow a vector space structure on the Lie algebra of $G$ using this bijection. Take $A,B\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(k)$, then we want $E(A)+E(B)=E(A+B)$, so do we define $(I_n+\varepsilon A) + (I_n+\varepsilon B):=I_n+\varepsilon (A+B)$? And then similarly, $\lambda(I_n+\varepsilon B)=I_n+\varepsilon\lambda B$?

As for a Lie bracket, we want $[E(A),E(B)]=E([A,B])=E(AB-BA)$, so $[I_n+\varepsilon A,I_n+\varepsilon B]:=I_n+\varepsilon (AB-BA)$?

Are these definitions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it right, it's just cumbersome to carry that $I_n$ around all the time, which is why no one does it. But yes, the way you define it in your last two paragraphs is the formally correct way to do it.

Once that is understood, of course everyone just says the Lie algebra "is" $\mathrm{Mat}_n(k)$ with its natural vector space structure, and the Lie bracket given by the matrix commutator. This Lie algebra is commonly called $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$, because, as you have proved, it naturally identifies with the Lie algebra of the algebraic group $GL_n(k)$.